# Linux shell script how to run a command after compilation is finished?

Tags: linux, shell, compilation

I would like to create a bash shell script to automate some tasks. In my case, I need to:

1. first compile some Fortran files
2. link them to create an executable,
3. run that executable.

I have done some searches and tried "&&" between commands, however, that does not seem to wait for my compilation to finish before it executes the link step. I have also tried "wait" command but it still does not wait till my compilation finishes. I could also pause it for some seconds before it executes the 2nd step, but the compiling time varies a lot each time.

Another way I can think of is, since after the compilation finishes it prints some messages to the terminal (like "compilation success"), I guess I can write a script to detect whether this message is generated, if yes, I can let it go ahead and link the compiled files to generate executable. I am wondering if there is a more direct way to achieve this purpose.

I guess I could also use MAKE file to do this job, but I would like to know some general solution using shell scripts.

Thank you!

Comment: Unless you're running commands in the background, they should run sequentially.

Comment: You need to show the script that's not working.

Comment: You don't even need `&&`, that's only needed if you want the second command to be run only if the first command was successful. Either way, they should run in order.

Comment: Hi Barmar. In my situation, the command that takes long to run is linking all the compiled fortran files and make an executable. It is a company internal command so I cannot post it here. I figured out the reason why && does not wait for it to finish. It is because somehow that command was running "in the background" (not sure I am describing it correctly). There is an option to bring that linking process to foreground, and after doing that, "&&" is able to wait for the linking to finish before execute the next command.  Thanks for your inputs!

Answer (score 1):

&& is the solution for that, you probably confuse syntax: either write all commands in a single line or use slash to split to lines:

`command1 && command2 && command3`

Or:

```
command1 && \
command2 && \
command3
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs! I figured the reason && does not work in my case: the command I used was running in the background. (I cannot post the command here because it is company internal command). After forceing that command to run in the foreground, && works for me.